# How to display the notification using service?

Tags: android, service, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I was trying to display the notifications using background service for which I wrote 3 classes. The service should run in background even if the appllication closed and and it should start running automatically so I used ,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<receiver android:name="com.s2si.ucom.ui.UcomBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

So in onReceive() of BroadcastReceiver class I am starting the service using,

```
Intent service = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
    context.startService(service);
```

In service class I am using AlarmManager to set particular interval so that I can display notification for every period of time. and finally I am invoking the BroadcastReceiver class to display the notification using AlarmManager. The problem is I am not getting the output :-(...instead of that I am getting error like, Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)... I am literally new to android coding...Can any one help me how to display notifications in such manner..and let me know what I did wrong above...Thanks much :-).

code in onCreate() method of service class,

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationServiceReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent
            .getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    // We want the alarm to go off 5 seconds from now.
    long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    firstTime += 5 * 1000;// start 5 seconds after first register.

    // Schedule the alarm!
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            firstTime, 5000, sender);// 5seconds interval
```

Comment: show some code of your service and your UcomBroadcastReceiver including the part where you are creating the broadcasts

Comment: Hi Daniel, actually I extended UcomBroadcastReceiver from BraodcastReceiver class in that I have overridden onReceive() method from where I called the service intent. That code I showed above 2 lines of code. Thank you for reply

Comment: will it work? or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: ur UcomBroadcastReceiver receives the event when the device completed boot up, and will start a service. Now that service creates a new broadcast, which receiver will receiver that broadcast?

Comment: no server will not create broadcast it will call receiver class which displays notifications

Comment: I have edited the service class code can u check it once

Comment: In that notificationServiceReceiver class I have written code for notification in onReceive()

Comment: you are not setting an action for that Intent, so no receiver will ever be notified

Comment: What I suppose to use as an action and why I need that? What happen if I use that?

Comment: Your supposed to name your intent so that android can decide how to handle it, an action is a String naming your intent, just as "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" is a name for a specific action, you need that name to declare which events your receiver will receive

Comment: I specified action name in manifest file but that receiver class was not called can you please show some piece of code to understand

Answer (score 1):

in short this is how you create a broadcast

```
private static final String ACTION_ALARM = "your.company.here.ACTION_ALARM";

public static void createAlarm(){
  Intent alarmIntent = new Intent();
  alarmIntent.setAction(ACTION_ALARM);

   PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
   AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

   am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timestamp for alarm, pi);
}

public void onReceive(...){
   //whatever is supposed to happen on receive
}
```

and you need to declare that broadcastreceiver and the actionname its supposed to receive in manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name="your.company.here.AlarmReciever">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="your.company.here.ACTION_ALARM" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<receiver android:name="com.s2si.ucom.ui.UcomBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver> I tried this but it is not working for me :(

Comment: do you receive the Boot_Completed event?

Comment: After completing the booting process receiver class will be called automatically and onReceive() code should be executed....for this do I need to receive the boot completed event then how to do it please let me know

Comment: yeah it should be called, my question is, if the receiver actually gets the call in your app, so that the onReceive from UcomBroadcastReceiver is triggered?

Comment: obsolutely!! why because, I gave that receiver's android name as UcomBroadcastReceiver but the problem is the statements of onReceive() was not executed why I got this problem? Do I need to specify any other permissions?